# Import class method and use as method in wrapper

Tags: python, oop

I have a class in a separate file called test_class.py. It looks something like this:

```
class test():
  def __init__(self, X, Y):
    self.X = X
    self.Y = Y

  def get_sum(self):
    return self.X + self.Y
```

I would now like to create a wrapper class that also has the `get_sum()` function as a method. This is what I'm trying (inspired and motivated by the problem in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7089719):

```
from test_class import test
tmp = test(1,3)
tmp.get_sum()
```

This outputs 4, so far so good. Now I try to create the wrapper as follows:

```
class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, method_name, module_name):
        self.get_sum = method_name
        self.test = module_name

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        method = __import__(self.module, globals(), locals(), [self.get_sum,])
        return method(*args, **kwargs)

wr = Wrapper('get_sum', 'test')
wr.get_sum()
```

Which just results in the following error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

I know this is because `wr.get_sum` evaluates to a string, but I don't know how to ensure I have access to the methods defined in my test class.

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: I think you've been confused by the very poor variable names of the `Wrapper` class you got from the previous post. The method being named in the other code isn't actually a method, but rather a top-level function (which is why it can be imported from a module). You could import the class you've created in your module, but not really its methods, which wouldn't work anyway without an instance. Can you be clear about why you want this? Are you having a pickling problem, like the questioner in the linked post? This may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/223254).

Comment: @Blckknght I see, the issue outlined in the other question is precisely my issue too. And it turns out that this is very much an XY problem, though what I care about is fixing the pickle error